# Python Deque appendleft with list

Tags: python, list, deque

I am currently creating my `deque` object using the following,

```
self.CommandList = deque((['S', False, 60],['c'],['g16'],['i50'],['r30', True],['u320'],['o5000'],['b1'],['B4500'],['W1'],['l5154'],['!10'],['p2', True, 10],['e1'],['K20'],['U0'],['Y0']))
```

But I wish to add a similar list to the queue later but using `appendleft`, so it can jump ahead of the list. I assumed the following, but had no luck.

```
NewList = (['S'],['c'],['!10'],['p4'],['o1200'],['i50'],['r30'],['b10'],['d1'],['A', True, 163])
self.CommandList.appendleft(NewList)
```

Is this even possible with `appendleft`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think you want [`.extendleft`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.deque.extendleft) here. This will "extend the list" instead of just appending the list as one element.

```
z = collections.deque([1,2,3,4])   # [1, 2, 3, 4]

z.appendleft(['bad', 'news'])   # [ ['bad', 'news'], 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
z.extendleft(['good', 'news'])  # [ 'good', 'news', ['bad', 'news'], 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
```

If they are getting inserted in reverse, the quick fix is to just reverse the list:

```
z.extendleft(reversed(['good', 'news']))
```

Comment: Hi. Because I am using multiple lists they actually get added in reverse! For example: self.CommandList.extendleft(['S'],['c'],['!10'],['p4']) ends up with p4 being first! How do I get around this?